# Redirecting to a new domain as well as structure at the same time

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Just having an issue redirecting a domain to another as well as changing the structure of the URL at the same time. I am using .htaccess using ISASPI.

I have 2 URLS and I would like to change the following:

http://www.example.co.uk/something-jobs/test-article-name/12345678

To

http://www.examplenew.co.uk/news/test-article-name/

My current rule looks something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^Something-Jobs/.*/ http://www.examplenew.co.uk/news/([^/]+)(?=/[^/]+/?$) [R=301,L]
```

Which of course is wrong. Any chance you could tell me where I am going wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's wrong. You can't use regex in RewriteTarget. modify your rule like this :

```
RewriteRule ^Something-Jobs/([^/]+)/[0-9]+$ http://www.examplenew.co.uk/news/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

You can also use RedirectMatch directive

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Something-Jobs/([^/]+)/[0-9]+$ http://www.examplenew.co.uk/news/$1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it has nearly worked! Just the last slash followed by the random numbers need to be removed from the RewriteTarget. As of now I am getting 

http://www.examplenew.co.uk/news/test-article-name/12345678

When it should be:

http://www.examplenew.co.uk/news/test-article-name/

Any ideas on this issue?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. Learn something new everyday :)